# Validation formula that TEXT should not to have SPACE

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, column, calculated-column, validation

Is there any validation formula which don't allow to save some value in column with SPACE in SharePoint 2010? I know that is Calculate column formula with TRIM formula but I need to validation formula to give Notification that user should remove SPACE from TEXT.

I will be very grateful for support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the column name is "NoSpace", the validation formula is:

=ISERROR(FIND(" ",NoSpace))

[image]

This is the NewItem form:

[image]